# ListView produces random ordered items

Tags: java, android, listview, layout-inflater

I am making an application that scans for particular bluetooth devices, then lists them on the device. The scanned devices will have parallel arrays for accessing data later.

**My problem:** After scanning devices, the ListView always seems to list the objects in random order. In other words, the first device scanned in, say device[0], will not align with MAC_address[0].

I need to get the ListView to populate the items in the order of which they are scanned in. From some research, I believe that my issue lies in inflation.

In the below image, you can see the items produced by the scan/ListView
[image]

However, you can see that the order of the items is different in my logging...
[image]

I have tested this, and clicking "Encode" on the first ListItem will attempt to encode the device with Mac Address 00:A0:50:CC:25:5F. My arrays all line up, just not the items. Thus, I need the items to be produced in the ListView in the correct order.

This is my SimpleAdapter from within onCreate()

```
// Instantiate the ListView
    resultsListView = findViewById(R.id.scan_screen_listview);
    resultsListView.setOnTouchListener(mGestureListener);

    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.scan_screen_list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.scan_screen_text1, R.id.scan_screen_text2})
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            if(convertView == null){
                Log.e("ConvertView", "ConvertView is NULL");
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.scan_screen_list_item, null);
            }

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Button b1 = v.findViewById(R.id.encode_btn);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Button Position", "Encode Position = " + position);
                }
            });

            // Button 2 setup
            Button b2 = v.findViewById(R.id.location_btn);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("Button Position", "Location Position = " + position);
                }
            });

            return v;
```

Here is the code for my "scan_screen_list_item.xml"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_screen_text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scan_screen_text2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#222222"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/encode_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Encode" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/location_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="Location" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your list using a `Comparator<T>` to ensure your order. Android can't ensure your needs.

```
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, String> a,
            Map.Entry<String, String> b) {
        return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you have an example of this? I have not used, or heard of, a Comparator. I will do some searching on this.

Comment: You use an array or a list of Strings? Or you provide a list of custom objects?

Comment: I am using a List of string objects, and passing values into a hash table's (value, key) parameters to get a 2-row list item